# How to make this Box Plot

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, data, charts, style

I want to mimic the following style (not necessarily the same data)

[image]

So far, I got the following

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{{1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 5, 10}, {1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 5, 10}},
 {{"Whiskers", Thick}, {"Fences", Thick}}, 
 ChartStyle -> {EdgeForm[{Black, 
     Thickness[.007]}], {RGBColor[{178, 34, 34}/255], 
    RGBColor[{100, 149, 237}/255]}}]
```

[image]

How can I:

1. Edit the median color and its thickness
2. Get the horizontal gray lines for integers
3. Detect and represent outliers as circles, if any

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[ParetoDistribution[3, 4], {2, 100}];

bwc = BoxWhiskerChart[data, 
  {{"Whiskers", Thick},
   {"Outliers", Style["○", Red]},
   {"MedianMarker", Directive[Thick, Yellow]}, 
   {"Fences", Thick}}, 
 ChartStyle -> {EdgeForm[{Black,Thickness[.007]}],
    {RGBColor[{178, 34, 34}/255], RGBColor[{100, 149, 237}/255]}}, 
 GridLines -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Post-process to move the median marker behind box edges:

```
Replace[bwc, {a___, b_PolygonBox, c___} :> {a, b, c, FaceForm[], b}, All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wondering if there is a way of getting the thickness of the `EdgeForm` to be in accordance with the `Thick` option for `Whiskers`, `Fences` and `MedianMarker`, instead of having to pick by hand the value `.007`. Nonetheless, perfect answer.

Comment: @samwolfe, Use `Thick` instead of `Thickness[.007]`?